# How can one choose the proper pressure setting on a water flosser (e.g., Waterpik)?

Tags: dentistry, floss-flossing

How can one choose the proper pressure setting on a water flosser (e.g.,  Waterpik)?

Below is what I have read and heard:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/9u18am/serious_dentists_of_reddit_whats_the_biggest/e90zult/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181104201244/https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/9u18am/serious_dentists_of_reddit_whats_the_biggest/e90zult/)):

   > Old folks who blast their perio pockets with a water pick on the highest settings, then wonder why their pockets are getting deeper. Please use a low setting on your water pick and don't sit with it in the same spot for a minute.
2. https://www.waterpik.com/oral-health/how-to-floss/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181104201959/https://www.waterpik.com/oral-health/how-to-floss/)):

   > Start with the lowest pressure setting, lean over the sink, place tip in your mouth.
3. A dentist I visited some time ago was recommending using the highest settings.
4. https://www.reddit.com/r/Dentistry/comments/9u6qob/how_can_one_choose_the_proper_pressure_setting_on/e9214l3/?context=3 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181104212407/https://www.reddit.com/r/Dentistry/comments/9u6qob/how_can_one_choose_the_proper_pressure_setting_on/e9214l3/?context=3)) (note: waterpik has 10 levels, where 10 is the highest pressure):

   > Our waterpik rep stated that it is most effective at a power level of 7.
5. https://www.waterpik.com/oral-health/pdfs/WP-100-instruction-manual ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181111223301/https://www.waterpik.com/oral-health/pdfs/WP-100-instruction-manual)):

   > Turn the pressure control
   >   dial on the base of the
   >   unit to the lowest setting
   >   (pressure setting No.1) for
   >   first-time use. Gradually
   >   increase pressure over
   >   time to the setting you prefer – or as instructed by
   >   your dental professional.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/TUhCsL
- https://redd.it/9u6qob

Comment: The manufacturer says use the lowest setting. Why do you doubt them?

Comment: @CareyGregory They say "*Start* with the lowest pressure setting". They don't specify what to do after the first few seconds.

Comment: @CareyGregory actually, https://www.waterpik.com/oral-health/pdfs/WP-100-instruction-manual ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181111223301/https://www.waterpik.com/oral-health/pdfs/WP-100-instruction-manual))  says "Turn the pressure control dial on the base of the unit to the lowest setting (pressure setting No.1) for first-time use. Gradually increase pressure over time to the setting you prefer – or as instructed by your dental professional." -> even the manufacturer is contradicting themselves…

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - I don't see how the manufacturer is contradicting themselves. Gradually find the setting you find most comfortable, unless a dentist says otherwise. That's not a contradiction, just a caution. I am closing this question as being answered with your own notations unless you can provide some evidence as why choosing by comfort level as written in their own instructions is erroneous.

Comment: @JohnP waterpik first quote say "*Start* with the lowest pressure setting". They don't specify what to do after the first few seconds. And the second quote for waterpik only mentions what they advise for the first time use. The waterpik quotes do not answer the question at all.

Comment: So...you're looking for a minute by minute guide on how to adjust a waterpik setting?

Comment: @JohnP just some guidelines. Only one quote out of 5 says the pressure has to be changed during a single utilisation btw.

Comment: Fine. I don't think guidelines in the specificity that you are looking for exist. However, I will let people attempt to find them.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Which quote says anything about changing pressure during a single utilization?

Comment: @BryanKrause the second one ("Start with the lowest pressure setting, lean over the sink, place tip in your mouth.") could be understood as such, though ambiguous.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That only says start lowest, just like (5) does. Although the directions are not a minute-by-minute guide I think it's pretty clear they are intended to read that you are to increase the pressure only over multiple uses, presumably to give enough time to register any discomfort.

Comment: @BryanKrause quote 2 is unclear whether it's start lowest for each session. Quote 5 clearly says "for first time use".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt So you can either assume they are contradicting themselves, or you could take the clear statement over the unclear one.

Comment: @BryanKrause "to the setting you prefer – or as instructed by your dental professional." is quite vague. I don't have any preference. I could ask my dentist but prefer some reference to complement their advice.